# Unexpected behavior with scala and URLClassLoader

Tags: scala

I found a wired behavior while trying to load a class with URLClassLoader.

A little bit of context: I have a trait at jar1 that looks like this:

```scala
trait ATrait { def act(context: Context): Unit }
```

and a class at jar2 that looks like this (jar2 got jar1 in his classpath at the IDE):

```scala
class EntryPoint extends ATrait {
  override def act(context: Context): Unit = {
    println(s"Hello World! context is = $context")
  }
}
```

and back at jar1 I have an entry point to the program that looks like this:

```scala
  private val classloader = new URLClassLoader(Array(jar2.toURI.toURL))
  private val myClass = classloader.loadClass(jar2ClassName)
  private val instance = myClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[ATrait]

  instance.act(null)
```

then, I tried to run the program form my IDE(IntelliJ + sbt) and it worked as expected.

later I ran jar1 form my cli with the scala command and I got this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: core.ATrait`, witch was weird because jar1 contains core.ATrait.

After a lot of tinkering around I crated a fat jar(with sbt assembly) form jar1 and ran it with the java command and it worked as expected.

So after this long story my questions are:

1. why doesn't the scala command works unlike java?
2. is there a different class loaders for java and scala?
3. is there a workaround that will let me run jar1 with scala?

Note: I am using scala 2.13

Edit:

The scala command was "scala -classpath .\jar1.jar core.EntryPoint .\jar2.jar"

And the java command was "java -classpath .\fatjar1.jar core.EntryPoint .\jar2.jar"
(I am passing jar2 location in args)

Comment: Can you post the exact command that you used to run jar1 from your command like interface?

Comment: @Виталий Олегович I added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of looking around its seems that the scala script uses an object called `MainGenericRunner` in order to run code, and that object use a `URLClassLoader` its self, so ya there is a different class loader between java.exe and the scala script.

The work around was to supply to java `scala-library.jar` in the classpath and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

The right command is with the class to run as last argument:

`scala -classpath .\jar1.jar .\jar2.jar core.EntryPoint`